# Am i allowed to sell a plugin for a application licensed under GNU

Tags: notepad++, gnu

If I make a plugin for notepad++, am I allowed to sell that plugin, or does it have to be free?

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon the whether the platform is under GPL as well, but if not:

> For sales or distribution, the entire source code need to be made available to end users, including any code changes and additions—in that case, copyleft is applied to ensure that end users retain the freedoms defined above.[55]

That information was [found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Use_of_licensed_software). See the other information in the section at the link, there are other aspects to know.